# Slim v3 how to send a response to a different URL / Ip address?

Tags: php, slim

i try to implement the paypal IPN with slim.

[see code here](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php)

they use curl to make a post request to an URL. Is it not possible to just change the URL in the slim response object?

other ways to send requests to somewhere with slim?

**EDIT**

I am talking about this line:

`$res = curl_exec($ch);`

what is the equivalent slim way to send a request to some url?

Answer (score 2):

You can send PSR7 Requests with the help of [HTTPlug](http://httplug.io/).

You have to create some Adapter classes to tell HTTPlug how to create Slims Request and Response objects. In your code you just create your Slim Request and call the Client with this. You can choose between some clients, for example Curl or Socket.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send your user to PayPal in order for them to pay, then you need to create a form on your website which POSTs to PayPal directly.

The code you linked to is a POST request from PayPal back to your server. To handle that in Slim, you create a `post` route:

```
$app->post('/paypal-ipn', PayPalIpnAction::class);
```

Within your Action class you need to send POST request back to PayPal:

```
class PayPalIpnAction
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $args)
    {
        $dataFromPaypal = $reqest->getParsedBody();

        // Validate data from PayPal using HTTPlug, Guzzle or
        // you use can the PayPal example code directly.

        // If data is valid, process data and do whatever you
        // need to with it.

        // All done. Return the response.
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Note that the verification step back to PayPal isn't directly related to the handling of the notification in Slim as it's part of your code for handling the notification.

Comment: i clarified my question